# Check if table is identical to select query

Tags: sql, select, equals

I have table with Static data (`states(id, name)`) AND table `user_states(user_id, state_id)`

How can i know if for some user (for example with id = '11') in table `user_states` are all recods from table `states` ?

If  table `states` has 50 states, then check if user with id '11' has all 50 states.

I read about solution, how to check if data of table is identical :

```
SELECT ul.location_id
FROM bt_user_location ul
    JOIN bt_location_region llr ON (ul.location_id = llr.id)
WHERE ul.user_id= 11
UNION
SELECT lr.id
FROM bt_location_region lr
```

If Count Rows of this query is bigger then count of any of this tables, than tables are not identical. But if one table has identical rows to another table but not all, then this query  will be not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Group By` and `Having`.

```
SELECT
    ul.user_id
    count(1)
FROM user_states
GROUP BY ul.user_id
HAVING count(1) = 50
```

This will count the number of states that each user has and will only return the users that have 50 states. If you want to check a specific user, add a `Where` clause. If user with id `11` doesn't have all 50 states, no rows will be returned.

```
SELECT
    ul.user_id
    count(1)
FROM user_states
WHERE ul.user_id = 11
GROUP BY ul.user_id
HAVING count(1) = 50
```

Comment: Does this assume the user doesn't have duplicate states? (ie: it's returning users with 50 states, not 50 distinct states?)

Comment: @Mike yes, this will assume that. My assumption is that a user will only have a state once (because why _would_ they have a state more than once?)

Comment: Thanks Dave. I just wanted to check I was understanding the SQL correctly. (And yes, you are correct, why would they!)